# ¿Como convertir a float la data que tengo en los hooks de React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Tengo 2 **hooks** que tiene la data en formato peso Argentino:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la funcion **Calculate()** tomo los valores de los **state** y los convierto a **parseFloat** para hacer un calculo de resta. La idea es **guardar el resultado de la resta en el state**. Pero obtengo **NAN** como resultado.
Del codigo lo que mas importa es la funcion **Calculate()** donde obtengo **NAN**, de todas formas les muestrolo que hice:

```js
const Home = () => {

const [stateOperations, setStateOperations] = React.useState([]);
const [incomeAmount, setIncomeAmount] = React.useState(0);
const [expensesAmount, setExpensesAmount] = React.useState(0);

const getOperations = async () => {
  const data = await operationsService.getOperationsByUser(user);
  setStateOperations(data);
  calculateAmounts(data);   
};

const calculateAmounts = (operations) => {
  let income = 0;
  let expenses = 0;
  operations.forEach(op => {
    let num = parseFloat(op.amount.toString());  
      if(op.type === 'ingreso'){   
        income += num;
      }else{
        expenses += num;
      }
    });   
    // Aca guardo en los state la data con formato peso Argenino
    setIncomeAmount(currencyFormat(income));
    setExpensesAmount(currencyFormat(expenses));  
}

const currencyFormat = (num) => {
   return Intl.NumberFormat('es-AR',{style:'currency',currency:'ARS'}).format(num);
}

// EN ESTA FUNCION OBTENGO NAN COMO RESULTADO en el console.log
const Calculate = async (amountOp, typeOp) => {
 let newTotal;
 let num = 0;
 const amount = parseFloat(amountOp);
 if(typeOp === 'ingreso'){
   num = parseFloat(incomeAmount);
   newTotal = num - amount;
   // obtengo NaN
   console.log('new resultado ingresos: ' +  newTotal);
   setIncomeAmount(currencyFormat(newTotal));
  }else{
    num = parseFloat(expensesAmount);
    newTotal = num - amount;
    // obtengo NaN
    console.log('new resultado egresos: ' +  newTotal);
    setExpensesAmount(currencyFormat(newTotal));
  } 
};

React.useEffect(() => {
 if (localStorage.getItem("user") !== null) {
   user = localStorage.getItem("user");
   getOperations();
 }
}, []);

 return(
   <div>
    // etc..
   </div>

 );

};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema seguro debe ser que estás intentando usar la función `parseFloat()` con precios en pesos que tienen el símbolo **$**.

La cuestión es que mientras tenga ese símbolo no lo va a poder convertir en float.

Por eso, te recomiendo que le saques ese símbolo **$** mediante la función `.split()`.

Al sacarle ese símbolo, recién ahí vas a poder transformarlos a float, hacer la resta y luego de eso volver a convertir los valores a precios otra vez.

Acá hay un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo:

```js
const currencyFormat = (num) => {
  return Intl.NumberFormat('es-AR',    {style:'currency',currency:'ARS'}).format(num);
}
    
console.log("Número en pesos: " + currencyFormat(188600))  
console.log("Número en pesos: " + currencyFormat(53900))

function priceToFloat(price) {
  
  let priceFloat = price.split('$')
  priceFloat =  priceFloat[1]
  priceFloat = parseFloat(priceFloat)


   console.log("Precio transformado a float: " + priceFloat)   
   console.log("Confirmando que el tipo de dato es: " + typeof(priceFloat))
   
   return priceFloat
}  

let price1 = priceToFloat(currencyFormat(188600)) 
let price2 = priceToFloat(currencyFormat(53900)) 

console.log("Resta de los dos floats y transformación a pesos: " + currencyFormat(price1 - price2) )
```

Ahí se ven los valores iniciales en pesos.

Luego esos valores los paso como argumentos a la función `priceToFloat()` que se encargará de quitarles el simbolo **$** para luego poder hacer el `parseFloat()`.

Esa función me devolverá los dos valores ya en floats los cuales puedo restar entre sí y volver a convertirlos en precios.